# Why isn't "background-image: url"working with Bootstrap carousel on WP?

Tags: plugins, images, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I made a Bootstrap carousel in plain HTML it was working just fine, but when I pasted the code into Wordpress the carousel is completely white.

It's not a problem with the path because it will work if I change it from

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("img/image01.png");"></div>
```

to

```
<img src="img/image01.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

then it works.

I know this seems like a HTML or CSS problem, but I feel like I've exhausted all options that I can think of, leading me to think it's something with Wordpress and Bootstrap not working together. I've tried changing **background-image:url** to just **background:url** but it still comes up with totally white.

I also know that if I try it on another div like:

```
<section id="schedule">
<div class="row" style="background-image: url('img/image01.png'); margin-top: 75px;">
<div class="callout-light text-center" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
<h1>Header!</h1>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

That it comes up just fine.

Here is the full code:

```
<style>
  .fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 }
</style>

<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/image01.png');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/image02.png');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/image03.png');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </header>
```

Comment: You will need to set a width and height to the `.fill` or it's parent container with pixels instead of percentage.

Comment: But wouldn't that defeat the purpose of making it responsive, to use fixed pixel width/height?

Comment: Oh, right. So only the height.

Comment: Well that makes it show up sure, but then I could just display the image as a <img> and not as a <div> with a "background:url", and that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm not following. What is the problem?

Comment: Here is a link to what I am trying to accomplish. http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/

You can see what I mean by changing the width and height of your browser window and watching the image continue to fill the page until you scroll down and view the rest of the site.

Setting a fixed height (or width) defeats the purpose of having a "Full" background carousel image, like in the link provided.

Comment: No, you will need to set the height no matter what. An `img` tag works because it has a defined height.

Comment: Correct, but that's not what I am trying to do. Please reread my question. I am trying to make the following code work:
     
    `<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("img/image01.png");"></div>`

Comment: I just told you, you must set a height to the parent div. I did MISREAD tho, knowing that you want the height to fill the entire window, you will set the parent containers to 100%.

Comment: Regardless, adding a fixed height in any way defeats the purpose of what I am trying to accomplish. I agree with you that I get some part of an image but it is not what I'm asking. Look at what happens to the background image of the link I mentioned earlier in the comments, when you change your browser window's height, to say something really small. It still shows up 100% height. Not more, not less. Make sure to scroll down after you've adjusted the window and you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35391/discussion-between-nathan-powell-and-user122552).

Comment: I also have `carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Sorry @Steve, but if you look at the full code, you can see that I have it written like you have it. Single quotes inside of double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(<?php 
    echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/img/image01.png);"></div>
```

You need to tell WordPress in "a WordPress-way" where to find the image...
Look in codex at [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("img/image01.png");"></div>
```

Your double quotes within double quotes will stop it from working, you need:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/image01.png');"></div>
```

Comment: extremely unlikely

Answer (score 0):

You should never use relative urls in wordpress except for css files. If "pretty permalink" something that works on one page might break on another. All urls should be absolute. The most you can get with usually is being relative to the protocol, but almost never anything more then that.